# Add data-attribute to Gutenberg block

Tags: block-editor

I have looked around and couldn't find a solution for this, what I am looking to do is add a data-attribute to the Gutenberg block

The perfect place for it would be the "Advanced" section with the CSS Class and HTML Anchor.  For example, if I add in `data-color`, there could be a label of "Color" with a text entry where I can add in `#FFFFFF`

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to add the data-attribute to _all_ blocks? Or just a single custom block?

Comment: All blocks that accept class,  it looks like this is a duplicate,  should be marked as soon